# angularjs $http interceptor will overwrite other http headers

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor

I am using $http interceptor to config my http headers.

```
app.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {
var _request = function (config) {
    config.headers = config.header || {};
    var authData = localStorageService.get('authData');
    if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }
    return config;
}
var _responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status == 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
return {
    request: _request,
    responseError: _responseError
}
}]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
}]);
```

Without using $http interceptor (which means if I comment

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor')
```

), my post method words fine.

```
$http.post(RoutePrefix + "api/accounts/create", dataToSend, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("succes!");
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error!");
    });
```

But if I use $http interceptor,
I will get 415(Unsupported media error).

```
message: "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource."
exceptionMessage: "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'CreateUserViewModel' from content with media type 'text/plain'."
exceptionType: "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"
```

Any solution or suggestion about my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's really `config.header` in `config.headers = config.header || {}` ? It seems like it removes all the existing headers on the request.

Comment: Yes, I think this should be fine. Because when I call post method, I add the content-type of header manually.

Comment: I don't think the interceptors work that way. It's actually intercepting the request you 'make', I mean you make the request with headers and before it gets sent to the server it gets intercepted by the request interceptor, and clear out the headers.

Comment: I think this line isn't necessary : `config.headers = config.header || {}`, it will definitely have headers in your case. Even if you don't give headers initially when making the request, the config object passed will have the headers property defined.

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
config.headers = config.header || {}
```

The right part is missing an ending `s` character after `header` word. Therefore `config.headers` gets initialised to `{}` because `config.header` is `undefined`.

But, even if it were written `config.headers = config.headers || {}`, I think it's not necessary at all nor wouldn't have any sense.